# Bash escape character

Tags: linux, bash, shell, escaping, character

I have this very reduced example of a bash command, where I want the $ sign escaped.
So the command :

```
su -m user -c "echo $test"
```

should print out:

```
$test
```

a simple \$test does not work unfortunately. I tried lots of other stuff but still couldn't find a solution. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put it in single quotes rather than double quotes.

```
su -m user -c 'echo \$test='
```

The single quotes keep the variable from being expanded by the original shell. The backslash then escapes the dollar sign in the shell run by `su`.

See [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash)

In answer to the comment, you can switch to double quoting to get single quotes into the string.

```
su -m user -c 'echo \$test='"'1'"
```

Comment: Thx Barmar! I missed something important. How to express it when I want $test='1' as result? su -m user -c 'echo \$test=\'1\'' does not work

Comment: Thx again, but the output is still just $test=1 ... did I miss something ? If I flip the whole quotes to this : su -m user -c "echo "'\$'"test=\'1\'" it works and prints $test='1'

Comment: It's hard to read code in comments, put backticks around it to make it more readable.

Comment: In general it's not easy to have nested command lines and nested quotes and escapes. Sometimes you need to double or triple the backslashes.